# Correct cache for Magento and settings

Tags: cache, optimization, memory

I'm optimizing the Magento store we have and would like to hear your opinion on the subject.

I have installed `mod-pagespeed` and now I want to add some aditional cache. I've found a lot of information on the subject and a bit confused witch one is better: `APC` or `mem_cache` or both?

Also what are the optimal settings, to minimize server response time.

We use VPN with Max of 4GB(2GB guaranteed) Ram.

Thanks, guys,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's probably worth differentiating between APC and Memcached so that you understand the difference.  Note that you also have both Memcache and Memcache**d**.  Of these 2 Memcache is the older option with some limitations, Memcached is a newer [faster](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/03/memcache-vs-memcached-php-benchmark/) solution (though neither are new).  So go with Memcached over Memcache.

With regards to Memcached vs APC, well they are both simple key/value memory based storage options.  Memcached is more versatile as it allows you to store data on an external server, with APC you can only store data on the local server but performance is considerably better.  Also worth noting is that APC is considered to now have a limited lifespan as from PHP 5.5 an equivalent opcode cache ships with PHP - Zend's opcache.  This however lacks the ability for you to store user data so APC is likely to continue to exist as a user key/value storage solution.

As for which you chose - well it's really up to you and what your requirement is for caching, but with only 2GB guaranteed memory I wouldn't advise using both APC and Memcached if they are both to reside on the local server as you need to leave enough memory to cater for other OS processes.  Personally I would always go with APC unless there was a requirement to store data on an external server.  Hopefully this gives you sufficient information to make a decision based on your requirements.

As for optimising server response time - well the first step is to ensure your server is configured optimally for your store and traffic.  There is no set configuration which can be applied to every setup as it really depends on things like the size of the store and the traffic the site sees.  There is plenty of advice out there so if you are not in a managed environment, the best bet might be to look at what other people have configured with a similar setup to yours a use that as a starting point for your setup.

If you can achieve something in the region of 1-2 seconds for generation of a full page of HTML then your server will be performing pretty well.  From that point if you want further performance improvements you can them implement a full page caching solution (there are many available including [ours](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/evolved-caching.html)) or Varnish to serve full page cached content with vastly reduced work for the server, and therefore much improved performance.  Remember however that FPC/Varnish is not a 'magic bullet', performance does need to be acceptable first as parts of the store such as the cart, checkout and customer login area will never be cached.

Comment: Thank you for such a deep answer. 

I will start by configurating APC first and see how it will affect the page load time. 

At the moment I've installed the mod_pagespeed and it improved site performance quite good. From 14-18s to 4-6s. I want to take it even further and make the page load in less than 3s.

Thank you very much for the explanation. I tryed to install the Varnish cache for frontend caching but it caused me problems. I don't know maybe my template is not optimized for it or something. But it damaged all the Frontend of the store.

Comment: If you are looking to use Varnish, you won't be able to use it 'out of the box' with Magento as it won't actually cache anything (by default it doesn't cache if cookies are present).  There are plenty of solutions out there you can try to use Varnish with Magento - both paid and free, but I would say get things setup well first, then look at Varnish/FPC.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest using both APC and Memcached.

While you may see many guides offering a "recommended" settings, it is actually just a general number as the settings differ depending on your store, visitors, server, etc.

I suggest going with the default setting and tweak it from there.